# scss gem error in application.css file ruby 2.1.5

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sass

I'm getting an error in my application.css.scss file.

```
Showing C:/Users/Vipvex/Documents/UCode/ucode/app/views/layouts/lms.html.erb where line #12 raised:

wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
  (in C:/Users/Vipvex/Documents/UCode/ucode/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
Extracted source (around line #12):              

       <title> UCode <% if content_for? :title %> - <%= yield :title %> <% elsif content_for? :heading %> - <%= yield :heading %> <% end %> </title>

       <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
       <link type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

       <%= jquery_include_tag :google %>
```

I think there might be a problem with scss gem.
One thing is that when I removed the .scss from the file it worked fine.

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.5'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.1'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

#gem 'compass', '~> 1.0'
gem 'sass'#  , '3.4.5'
gem 'sass-rails'#, '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'coffee-rails'

gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'slick_rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails-cdn'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'liquid'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.3.1'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'ruby-saml-idp'


gem 'jquery-slick-rails'
gem 'validates_email_format_of'
gem 'tzinfo-data'


# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you post your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss?

Comment: I have tried deleting everything the the file yet it still gave me the same error with no code. I do not think the code is the issue.

Comment: Lets look at your app/views/layouts/lms.html.erb file then.

Comment: Also might try doing a bundle update, and then restarting rails

Comment: Can you try to change your Gemfile like:
```gem 'sass-rails', github: 'rails/sass-rails', branch: '4-0-stable'```
That should fix your problem.

Comment: Could you post that as an answer?